# How to read information outside of collection in XML Item Reader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, jaxb2

I am creating a Spring Batch job that needs to read data from an XML file sent over from an outside source. If I have an XML document that is structured like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RootElement rootAttribute="attribute value">
    <HeaderInformation>
        <HeaderItem>Value</HeaderItem>
        <SomeElement>Value</SomeElement>
    </HeaderInformation>
    <Records>
        <RecordItem>
            <ElementOne>Value</ElementOne>
            <ElementTwo>Value</ElementTwo>
        </RecordItem>
        <RecordItem>
            <ElementOne>Value</ElementOne>
            <ElementTwo>Value</ElementTwo>
        </RecordItem>
        <RecordItem>
            <ElementOne>Value</ElementOne>
            <ElementTwo>Value</ElementTwo>
        </RecordItem>
    </Records>
</RootElement>
```

I can very easily read the necessary RecordItems using the StaxEventItemReader and Jaxb2Marshaller. However the problem arises that I need to be able to reference some of the information outside of this "Records" collection. For example, would there be a way through either the Jaxb bindings or Spring ItemReader configuration to pull the rootAttribute value from the RootElement?

Using the given example the final result I'm looking for is to be able to write ElementOne, ElementTwo, and rootAttribute to a database for each RecordItem.